# Calling variable functions with static variables

Tags: php

*Approach 1* would work, but *Approach 2* would not - it whould result in a fatal error (*Function name must be a string in...*)

```
# Approach 1
$function = self::$function and $function();

# Approach 2
self::$function and self::$function();
```

Isn't this a bit strange? I hope someone could explain.

---

Edit: To give some context, here's a whole class:

```
class Example
{
    static $function;

    static function method()
    {
        self::$function();
    }
}

function callback() {}

Example::$function = 'callback';
Example::method();
```

Comment: I need to see your class In order to help you.

Comment: @aguyfromhere, What do you want to see? It could be an empty class with a static method and a static variable - $function.

Comment: I agree with @aguyfromhere, can you provide 2 complete examples? I am not sure I understand what you are doing.

Comment: It can't be an empty class if you're going to call the function using () at the end there.

Comment: @MathieuImbert, I added a class.

Comment: Seems like a case of ambiguous syntax. It thinks you want to call `$function()` on `self`. I don't know if there's a workaround except to assign to a variable first.

Comment: @deceze, Nope. Adding a method called `callback` to the class changed nothing. This was no surprise as the error message sais nothing about undefined methods.

Comment: **WTF** PHP, WTF... still trying to wrap my head around why #1 works the way it does. `$function = self::$function && $function();` does *not* work!

Comment: No, it tries to find a variable "`$function`" which it expects to hold a method name. That variable doesn't exist, is `null`, not a string, hence the error. Compare with `$obj->$method()`.

Comment: @Jon The precedence of `&&` and `and` are different. `=` has a higher precedence than `and` but lower than `&&`.

Comment: @deceze: Just figured that out, thanks. Oh, and regarding the mere presence of `and`: WTF PHP... ;-)

Comment: @deceze, I don't understand. If it did what you say it does, it would work. There is a variable `$function` and it does hold a method name.

Comment: No, there's a variable `self::$function`. There's no variable `$function`.

Comment: @deceze, You are right. I added a `$function` variable to the method scope and it read it. It seems like the `()` has a higher precedence than `self::`.

Comment: Not sure it could be called a "precedence" thing, I'd rather say `self::$function()` works with the same logic as `$obj->$method()`, for better or worse.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in curly brackets? `{self::$function}();` not at my computer at the moment, so unable to test it

Comment: @thaJeztah: Parse error. The compiler is really dumb (in general, not in this specific case) and tries to parse the block without taking the presence of `()` into account. Of course `self::$function` is legal (even though it does nothing), but then we come to the missing semicolon...

Comment: Interesting. Of course, you can go with call_user_func(), but interesting anyway :)

Comment: I think the existing answers are fine, no need to add a one-sentence answer. :)

Comment: @deceze, I don't agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get into technical details of precedence and ambiguity, the short explanation is that `self::$function()` works according to the same logic as `$obj->$method()`; it tries to call the variable function `$function()` of `self`.

Comment: It either ignores `self::` or it thinks of `self` as of the scope of the current function.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax seems ambigous to me. Probably it is for PHP too. It would be more clean, and functional to either save the function name in a local variable:

```
static function method()
  $method = self::$function;
  $method();
}
```

Or use `call_user_func()`:

```
static function method()
  call_user_func(self::$function);
}
```

Comment: What is the ambiguity here, in what other way could it be interpreted and why wouldn't the error message say something about it.

Comment: p.s. I'm not interested in how to make it work. I know how. The question says it. I'm only interested in why.

Comment: The ambiguity is the scope. Are you applying th function `()` on `$function`? `self::$function()`. So the answer to why is: because it's ambigous. If you are really interested in technical reasons, read PHP source.

Comment: @MathieuImbert: It's not exactly that ambiguity -- you cannot apply `()` to `$function`, because the only sane result would be for the expression as a whole to evaluate to the value of a static property whose name is the result of evaluating `$function()`. But if that were allowed, then `Foo::bar()` should also be a candidate for "the value of the static property of `Foo` whose name is the result of evaluating a call to the free function `bar`". The madness would never end.

Answer (score 1):

### Why approach #1 works

It's an artifact of PHP's operator precedence.

```
$function = self::$function and $function();
```

is equivalent to

```
($function = self::$function) and $function();
```

which is of course equivalent to

```
$function = self::$function;
if ($function) $function();
```

The last line works fine because that's the syntax for [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

### Why approach #2 does not work

Because there's ambiguity, which the compiler resolves "the wrong way".

Consider this:

```
self::$function();
```

Does this mean that PHP should invoke a callback stored in the `static` property `$function`, or that it should invoke a static method whose name is the value of the variable `$function`?

PHP goes with the latter but there's no variable `$function` in scope, resulting first in a notice and then in an error (`$function` evaluates to `null`, which is not a string).

Comment: Just `self::$function();`, as you suggest, would result in the same error. The issue has nothing to do with comparison operators. The only reason I used them in the question is to express the fact that the variable is not NULL.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: Sorry, I didn't get that at all. Are you referring to #1 or to #2? What comparison operators?

Comment: Sorry, I meant logical operators.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: So my explanation of #1 tells you nothing that you didn't already have in mind? I 'm having trouble understanding what exactly it is you object to.

Comment: Yes. It's not about the logical operators. I'm sorry if the question doesn't makes it clear. The last comment of deceze has the answer.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: That's true, but I 'd like to think this answer also explains why. Doesn't it?